# wordpress plugin activate/deactivate function not firing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have to do some catalog plugin for wordpress but I am already having troubles with only activating / deactivating it. Here is my code. It should work. This code is only testing code for activate / deactivate, but considering the documentation, this should work and it seems I cannot find reasonable argument, why this is not firing. Can someone be so kind and take a look at the code? Thanks in advance

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plus8k_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'plus8k_deactivate' );

function plus8k_activate()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plus8k_products"; 

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name tinytext NOT NULL,
      description text NOT NULL,
      meta tinytext NOT NULL,
      content text NOT NULL,
      time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
      status bool DEFAULT 'true' NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plus8k_media";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name tinytext NOT NULL,
      caption text NOT NULL,
      location tinytext NOT NULL,
      time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
      prod_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id),
      FOREIGN KEY (prod_id)
        REFERENCES " . $wpdb->prefix . "plus8k_products(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) $charset_collate;";

    dbDelta( $sql );
}

function plus8k_deactivate()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plus8k_products"; 

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "DROP TABLE $table_name";

    dbDelta( $sql );

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plus8k_media";

    $sql = "DROP TABLE $table_name";

    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

If I for instance remove functions and just copy the code from plus8k_activate outside function, the tables get created. I don't know why the registered hook doesn't fire the plus8k_activate function.

EDIT! Activate didn't work because error in sql (boolean default must be 1 or 0, it doesnt recognize true/false)

Now activate work, but deactivate doesn't although sqls are ok, I've tryed it with phpmyadmin. Need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you call this function from the main file of your plugin (like `sample-plugin/sample.php`).

Alternatively try the anonymous function callback to ensure that you are not making any mispelings etc.

```
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, function () {
   //something here like
   die('today');
});
```

When you deactivate your plugin this code has to run. Please take it from there adding your functions inside.

Comment: "Mispelings" is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay to me.
Make sure your filename is like your plugins name. E.g. if your plugin is called `myplugin`, the activation script needs to be in `wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php`

To remove the table, you can't use `dbDelta()` - this will only create the table or modify it, but not remove it.

To drop a table, you need a regular query:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plus8k_products"; 
$sql = "DROP TABLE $table_name";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```